# Checking equality between variable and object

Tags: ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my program to properly check for equality between the Exterior Finish(ext)and the object instances I had created before hand. Is instance_of? the issue here, as in I am not using it correctly?

```
##################################################
class Wood
end

class Brick
end

class Other
end
#################################################
asbestos =              Wood.new     #'Wood'
cement_board =          Wood.new     #'Wood'
frame_clapboard =       Wood.new     #'Wood'
vinyl =                 Wood.new     #'Wood'
asphalt =               Wood.new     #'Wood'
wood_shake =            Wood.new     #'Wood'

brick_stone =           Brick.new    #'Brick'
brick_stone_veneer =    Brick.new    #'Brick'
concrete =              Brick.new    #'Brick'

glass =                 Other.new    #Other Not Supported
other =                 Other.new    #Other Types Not Supported
stucco =                Other.new    #Not Suppored
aluminum =              Other.new    #Not supported
#################################################

puts "Enter name of Exterior Finish: "
ext = gets.chomp

puts"Enter year of building completion: "
year =  gets.chomp

if ext.instance_of? Wood

  puts "Tis Wood\n"

  if year.to_i.between?(1850, 1942)
    print "pre war wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1943, 1977)
    print "post war wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1978, 2005)
    print "near present wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(2006, 2014)
    print "present wood\n"
  end

elsif ext.instance_of? Brick

  puts "Tis Brick\n"

  if year.to_i.between?(1850, 1942)
    print "pre war brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1943, 1977)
    print "post war brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1978, 2005)
    print "near present brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(2006, 2014)
    print "present brick\n"
  end

else

  print "Of Type Not Supported\n"

end
```

Comment: You get `ext` from console. It's a string. Certainly it is not one of your classes defined above.

Comment: You probably need something like `if ext == 'Wood'`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ext is supposed to be the string I compare the objects in the classes to. In pseudo code: if ext == x in class Wood. X being one of the instances or objects in class Wood like asbestos as in my code above.

Comment: Well, you can't compare strings to classes, it makes no sense. You need to turn those strings into objects (`eval` would work. There are other ways too)

Comment: Also, you need `is_a?`, not `instance_of?`. For example, `"foo"` is_a `Object`, is instance_of `String`, but not instance_of `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Wood
end

class Brick
end

class Other
end
#################################################
asbestos =              Wood.new     #'Wood'
cement_board =          Wood.new     #'Wood'
frame_clapboard =       Wood.new     #'Wood'
vinyl =                 Wood.new     #'Wood'
asphalt =               Wood.new     #'Wood'
wood_shake =            Wood.new     #'Wood'

brick_stone =           Brick.new    #'Brick'
brick_stone_veneer =    Brick.new    #'Brick'
concrete =              Brick.new    #'Brick'

glass =                 Other.new    #Other Not Supported
other =                 Other.new    #Other Types Not Supported
stucco =                Other.new    #Not Suppored
aluminum =              Other.new    #Not supported
#################################################

puts "Enter name of Exterior Finish: "
ext = gets.chomp
ext=eval (ext) rescue nil # this will convert entered text to corresponding class or instance or if user enter invalid text then it will set ext = nil

puts"Enter year of building completion: "
year =  gets.chomp

if ext.is_a? Wood

  puts "Tis Wood\n"

  if year.to_i.between?(1850, 1942)
    print "pre war wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1943, 1977)
    print "post war wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1978, 2005)
    print "near present wood\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(2006, 2014)
    print "present wood\n"
  end

 elsif ext.is_a? Brick

  puts "Tis Brick\n"

  if year.to_i.between?(1850, 1942)
    print "pre war brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1943, 1977)
    print "post war brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(1978, 2005)
    print "near present brick\n"

  elsif year.to_i.between?(2006, 2014)
    print "present brick\n"
  end

else

  print "Of Type Not Supported\n"

end
```

Comment: This works only if I type in Wood or Brick, but the intention is to use asbestos or aluminium or stucco as inputs, and then checking to see if those are in fact in the class wood or brick.

Comment: It's been updated now it'll accept any of the instance declared